# How to limit the related search in people search results page

Tags: search, search-scope, people-search

The built-in People core results web part includes a link in the section for each person to show more results by the same person.  We want to designate the scope of the 'also by' query so we can exclude results that are in the index but are located on the network.  We already have a 'portal' scope but when we looked into the secondary query, we cannot find the where the actual query is performed.  We assumed that, like in other search queries, we could include a scope parameter in the query but we have to locate the query first.

Any idea where the 'by same author' query is or otherwise control the scope it uses?

We are using SharePoint 2010 Enterprise.